# Cassandra eating up all the off heap memory

Tags: cassandra, datastax

DB used: Datastax cassandra community 3.0.9
Cluster: 3 x (8core 64GB AWS) with 300GB io1 with 3000iops.
Java heap memory allocated = 8g
Write consistency: Quorum , read consistency: ONE Replication factor: 3

Problem: I loaded our servers with 50,000 users and each user had 1000 records initially and after sometime, 20 more records were added to each users. I wanted to fetch the 20 additional records that were added later(Query : select * from table where userID='xyz' and timestamp > 123)

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    userID text,
    timestamp timestamp,
    ....
    PRIMARY KEY (userID, timestamp)
);
```

I have added additional 200GB of data into the tbl apart from the original data for 50,000 users.

Heap memory usage is in the range 2-4 GB but almost all the remaining off heap memory (56 GB) is eaten up by cassandra.

From this point onwards, if more data is added to the table, a sharp decline in read throughput is observed due to unavailable memory.

Though, it meets the read throughput SLA, but does not seem to be a scalable solution - (3 x 64 GB) RAM for 200 GB data.

Note:

- In the load test experiment, records for the only initial 50,000 users
  are being fetched.
- Row cache is disabled.
- It's read intensive application - 2000 reads / sec

What could be the possible reason for high off heap memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

If your partitions are very large then read times take longer. Since your data is partitioned by userid, all data associated with each user id is stored in a single partition on disk (within the partition, your data is ordered by the timestamp- your clustering key). When reading, cassandra must traverse the whole partition to find the data you are requesting in the read. If each userid has a lot of data associated with it, you could have quite large partitions on disk which will take longer to read.

Comment: My partitions are not very large, for each user there are no more than 1020 records. Also in load test I am repeatedly reading records for the first 50,000 users only which sums up to just 4.5 GB of data. So, my query is -  what is filling up the 50GB (off-heap) memory when row cache is disabled.

Comment: What do you mean by repeatedly? does a single read record set for all 50,000 users sum up to 4.5 GB? or the total sum of all queries?

Comment: @daniel: Total data for 50k users sums up to be 4.5GB. Repeatedly means that data for only 50k users is being read and the additional 200GB is not read in the test

Comment: Every user has 1020 records and each query is fetching last 20 records for a user. There are 150,000 users but in the load test, I am repeatedly fetching records for first 50,000 users only (one by one)  => (50,000 users * 1020 records) = 4.25 GB